# Network activity indicator and asynchronous sockets

Tags: objective-c, sockets, networking, nonblocking

I have an app which continuously reads status updates from a server connection.

All is working well with a stream delegate to handle all the reading and writing asynchronously.

There's no part of the app that is "waiting" for a specific response from the server, it is just continuously handling status updates as they sporadically arrive from the socket.  There are no requests on the client side that are waiting for responses.

I'm wondering what the best practice would be for the network activity indicator in this case.

I could turn it on in the stream event handler, and off before we leave the handler, but that would be a very short time (just enough for an non-blocking read or write to occur).  Trying this, I only see the faintest flicker of the indicator; it needs to be on longer than just during the event handler.

What about turning it on in the stream delegate, and setting a timer to turn it off a short time later?  (This would ensure it's on long enough to be seen, rather than the short time spent in the stream delegate.)

Note: I've tried this last idea: turning on the network activity indicator whenever there's stream activity, and note the NSDate; then in a timer (that I have fired every 1 second), if the time passsed is >.5 second, I turn off the indicator.  This seems to give a reasonable indication of network activity.

Any better recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If the network activity is continuous then it sounds like it might be somewhat annoying to the user, especially if it's turning on and off all the time.

Perhaps better would be to test for *lack-of-response* up to a certain timeout value and then display an alert view to the user if you aren't getting any response from the server.  Even that could be optional if you can provide feedback (like "Last update: 5 mins ago") to the user instead.

Comment: The status updates aren't continuous, but sporadic (every minute or so).  I'm not married to having the network activity indicator updated; however, is not using the indicator when you are using the network grounds for App Store rejection?

Comment: @Dale Yeah, I'm not sure about Apple rejecting the app; it's certainly possible.